# How to use Managed Identity to authenticate calls to Azure REST API using Azure SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-sdk-.net

I've got a .NET 6 web API that is deployed as a web app in Azure. This API has a service that calls the Azure REST API to get a list of resources in our Azure. I'm using the Azure SDK with the following line to create the client:

`var client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());`

This is working fine in my local development environment (using my active directory account with high access levels), but when I deploy to Azure and a User Assigned Managed Identity is used, the only resource that is returned is the managed identity itself.

How do I configure the Managed Identity to be able to see all Azure resources?

Thanks.

I've tried giving the Managed Identity Reader permissions on the subscription level.

Comment: There are more than one type of credential.  You are using a Windows Credential. Most systems are moving to OAUTH2 which works on Windows, Linux, and Mac.  The server can be configured to use either Windows or OAUTH2.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/troubleshooting-authentication-azure-hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `DefaultAzureCredential` will attempt to use `ManagedIdentityCredential` when running in Azure. `ManagedIdentityCredential` will use a system-assigned managed identity by default. You can configure the credential type to use the user-assigned managed identity as follows:

```
var client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential(
    new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId
    }));
```